# Building string using substring constructor- debugging - when step over code continues automatically?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
//Open a file

//Put contents in to a char array
char* current_bytes = static_cast<char*>(region->get_address());

//Create a string 
std::string my_string(current_bytes, x, 16);
```

`x` = 202

`current_bytes` contains 100,000,000 bytes

When I am debugging (in debug mode in Visual Studio) and I step over the string constructor, the code just automatically continues??

I did think it could be because I create the string on the stack and so I tried this:

```
std::string my_string = new std::string(current_bytes, x, 16);
```

but that also did the same odd thing of the code automatically continuing when I stepped over it in debug mode....

Comment: You don't need to use `new` with things like `string` or `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your constructor with VS you need to set up a break point within it otherwise it will continue.